# How to print out time for every output data

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, adafruit

I am trying to retrive my data from a sensor through BeagleBone Black. I got reading and volts, but since I allready use time for time.sleep(). time.sleep() gets syntax error  when I try to incorporate start_time.

```
start_time = time.time()
seconds = (time.time() -start_time)
print('%f\t%f\%s' % (reading, volts, seconds)
```

This is the code block I try to write.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
import time

sensor_pin = 'P9_40'

    ADC.setup()
    
    print('Reading\t\tVolts')
    
    while True:
        reading = ADC.read(sensor_pin)
        volts = reading * 1.800
        print('%f\t%f' % (reading, volts)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Why do I get syntax error and is there a better way to add time in seconds?
Syntax Error:

```
File "pulse.py", line 15
    time.sleep(0.5)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you post the messages from the SyntaxError that you are seeing? Your `time.time()` usage should not result in an exception.

Comment: Also what time difference are you trying to measure?

Comment: @Diego Say I get a Reading 1 second after I started the script. I want to print out Volt: 1.3 at 1.000 second.

Comment: @Aryan It's the time.sleeps() who gets a syntax error. I was not clear in the text.

Comment: Can you copy the text of the syntax error into your question please?

Comment: @HPringles Updated with the syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here is that you haven't closed the parentheses `()` on the line above the `time.sleep`.

It should read as below

`print('%f\t%f' % (reading, volts))`

You have the same issue in the print statement you used when calculating the time difference

Comment: This is considered **old style formatting**: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#1-old-style-string-formatting-operator

Comment: It is, yes. However, the post was asking for the reasons behind the syntax error, not about the semantics of the code

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [f-string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

```
print(f'{reading} {volts} {seconds}')
```